# SOLR Related facet search

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet

I am using SOLR and i have a schema something Like this :

```
<fields>
<field name="Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="Username" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/>
 <field name="ServerName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<fields/>
```

I want to use facet to get the result that give me the number of user per each server
how can i do that?

desired result :

> server 1 : 200 (userNumber) 
>   server 2: 300 
>   and so on...

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, as i do not have your data and schema. But what i think you need is pivot Faceting `http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting` .

So you need to do something like this (again , you need to adjust this to make it work for you)

```
http://ip:port/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.pivot=Username,ServerName
```